# Need to add " " on a target of different strings in a txt file

Tags: command-line, sed

hope everyone is ok. Want to add " " on a txt file

for example :

```
12  maker_ITAG  gene    64046325    64049958    .   +   .   gene_id Solyc12g057010.2
12  maker_ITAG  mRNA    64046325    64049958    .   +   .   ID=transcript:Solyc12g057010.2.1
12  maker_ITAG  exon    64046325    64046330    .   +   .   Parent=transcript:Solyc12g057010.2.1
12  maker_ITAG  CDS 64046325    64046330    .   +   0   ID=CDS:Solyc12g057010.2.1
12  maker_ITAG  exon    64046523    64046849    .   +   .   Parent=transcript:Solyc12g057010.2.1
12  maker_ITAG  CDS 64046523    64046849    .   +   0   ID=CDS:Solyc12g057010.2.1
12  maker_ITAG  exon    64047204    64047961    .   +   .   Parent=transcript:Solyc12g057010.2.1
```

i need to add only to the string after the `gene_id`, so it becomes `gene_id "Solyc12g057010.2"`
there are multiple gene_id s in my txt file. This was an example.

thanks

Comment: its an 80mb txt file with thousands of lines.

Comment: Alright, that is basic Sed usage. I believe you could give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` with capture groups for this purpose:

```
sed -r 's/(gene_id\s)(.*)$/\1"\2"/' in-file.txt
```

Add `-i.bak` in order to do the changes in the file and create a backup file.

Comment: Hi, @JimHat. What you mean it didn't work? I've created a file, based on you sample and it works!

Comment: hey, i copied the command you posted and it didnt work. I also made an example file with the sample i posted and still didnt work.

Comment: @JimHat, did you change `in-file.txt` with the actual file name?

Comment: yes. sed -r 's/(gene_id\s)(.*)$/\1"\2"/' Solanum_lycopersicum.SL3.0.48_test.txt > test1.txt

Comment: @JimHat, I can't figure out where the problem could be. You can tray to change `\s` with regular whitespace or with `[[:space:]]`. Or give a try without it.

Comment: it works for me too

Comment: @JimHat, another possible syntax, without the option for extended regex, is  `sed 's/\(gene_id\s\)\(.*\)$/\1"\2"/' in-file.txt`.